# Erro no tkinter sobre um objeto label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Primeiramente boa tarde amigos,
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação POO no python e meu objeto retornou o seguinte erro:

```py
  File "codigo_principal.py", line 37, in <module>
    menu=Autenticar(["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],('400x150'),"MENU",True)
  File "/home/bart/teste/janela.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.nome=Criar_Label(self.root,"NOME",xy[0],xy[1],fonte,fundo)
  File "/home/bart/teste/criar_widgets.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.label=Label(root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
```

Procurei a documentação do Python, mais especificamente do Tkinter e percebi que esse erro geralmente ocorre quando há problemas de janelas ao destruir a anterior para criar uma nova. Entretanto no meu caso não estou tentando fazê-lo, meu código até agora só tem uma janela!

Segue os arquivos que formam o código:
1- codigo_principal.py

```py
from janela import *
menu=Autenticar(["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],'400x150'),"MENU",True)
```

2- janela.py

```py
from tkinter import *
from criar_widgets import *

class Janelas:
   def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original):
     #Caso seja a janela mãe
     if original:
          #Esta é a variável da janela mãe
          self.root = Tk()
     #Caso seja uma janela filha

     else:
          #Esta é a variável da janela filha
          self.root= Toplevel()

     #Esta é a cor de fundo da janela
     self.root["bg"]=fundo
     #Este é o título
     self.titulo=Criar_Label_Titulo(self.root,titulo,fonte,fundo)
     #Este é o tamanho da janela
     self.root.geometry(tela)
     self.root.mainloop()

class Autenticar(Janelas):
    def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original):

        super().__init__(fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original)

        self.nome=Criar_Label(self.root,"NOME",xy[0],xy[1],fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_nome=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+50,xy[1],fonte,fundo,False)  

        self.senha=Criar_Label(self.root,"SENHA",xy[0],xy[1]+30,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_senha=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+50,xy[1]+30,fonte,fundo,True)

        self.botao=Criar_Button(self.root,"INSERIR NOME",fonte,fundo,lambda:login(self.root,usuario,senha))

    def login(self,usuario,senha):
        if usuario == "" and senha == "":
           pass
            #self.root.destroy()
```

3- criar_widgets.py

```
from tkinter import *

class Criar_Label:
    def __init__(self,root,texto,abcissa,ordenada,fonte,fundo):
         self.label=Label(root)
         self.label["text"]=texto
         self.label["font"]=fonte
         self.label["bg"]=fundo
         self.label.place(x=abcissa,y=ordenada)

#Será que deveríamos fazer polimorfismo aqui e fazer da classe Criar_Label a classe mãe?
class Criar_Label_Titulo:
    def __init__(self,root2,texto,fonte,fundo):
         self.titulo=Label(root2)
         self.titulo["text"]=texto
         self.titulo["font"]=fonte
         self.titulo["bg"]=fundo
         self.titulo.pack()

class Criar_Entry:
    def __init__(self,root2,abcissa,ordenada,fonte,fundo,segredo):
         self.entry=Entry(root2,font=fonte)
         self.entry.place(x=abcissa,y=ordenada)
         if segredo:
             self.entry["show"]="*"

class Criar_Button:
    def __init__(self,root2,texto,fonte,fundo,comando):
         self.button=Button(root2)
         self.button["text"]=texto
         self.button["font"]=fonte
         self.button["bg"]=fundo
         self.button["command"]=comando

         self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Até chegar a abrir a janela e colocar um widget label,mas trava e quando fecha dá o erro. A documentação que estudei para chegar à conclusão de que é um erro de abrir ou fechar uma janela são as seguintes páginas:

1- A página do próprio stack overflow

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655219/whats-the-difference-between-tkinters-tk-and-toplevel-classes
```

2- O reddit

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/cx4lu9/cant_invoke_label_error_using_tkinter_on_python_36/
```

Não sei se interpretei mal a documentação ou não, mas o erro existe e não sei corrigí-lo.

Grato

Comment: aparentemente a label não tem uma referencia na memoria, por isso ela é destruida, acredito que vc pode simplificar seu codigo, depois que arrumar a referencia da label, vai ter o mesmo problema com a entry

Comment: fiquei perdido agora, testei todas as classes, e elas funcionam bem, só da erro quando chama a classe autenticar, não faço ideia do pq

Comment: Então... Estou na mesma... Até entendo dar erro ali, mas n sei o pq desse erro em esoecífico(já que se trata de um erro de mudança de janelas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolvi o problema invertendo a herança

no seu codigo vc cria

```
class Janelas
class Autenticar(Janelas)
```

se vc inverter para

```
class Autenticar
class Janelas(Autenticar)
```

e corrigir a chamada do **super()**, o codigo roda mostrando as label e entry sem problemas

aqui esta como eu organizo meus aplicativos, vc pode ver que as configurações estão em outras classes

```
from gui import GUI
from gerador import Gerador
from conf import Setup
from mapas import ZipA

class App(GUI, Gerador, Setup, ZipA):
    VER = 'Maio/2019'

app = App()
```

**GUI** é a classe que cuida do design

**Setup** é a classe que liga a funcionalidade com o design

---

vi como esta o codigo no git, eu pensei em uma media um pouco diferente

```
class Autenticar:
    def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original):
        self.nome=Criar_Label(self.root,"NOME",xy[0],xy[1],fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_nome=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+50,xy[1],fonte,fundo,False)  

        self.senha=Criar_Label(self.root,"SENHA",xy[0],xy[1]+30,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_senha=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+50,xy[1]+30,fonte,fundo,True)

        self.botao=Criar_Button(self.root,"INSERIR NOME",fonte,fundo,lambda:login(self.root,usuario,senha))

    def login(self,usuario,senha):
        if usuario == "" and senha == "": 
           pass
            #self.root.destroy()

class Janelas(Autenticar):
   def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original):
     if original:
          self.root = Tk()

     else:
          self.root= Toplevel()
     super().__init__(fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo,original)

     self.root["bg"]=fundo
     self.titulo=Criar_Label_Titulo(self.root,titulo,fonte,fundo)
     self.root.geometry(tela)
     self.root.mainloop()


menu=Janelas(["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],'400x150',"MENU",True)
```

Comment: Existe um problema ao fazê-lo, que no caso é justamente a solução... Eu criei a classe janela para que eu consiga fazer várias janelas mais facilmente através da classe mãe. Esta classe em questão possui características que todas as janelas em meu código teriam(como a de background cor, a fonte ou o Label título). O fato é: se eu inverter, não estaria facilitando, mas dificultando. Mas muito obrigado pelo alerta de inverter a herança, agora sei que o problema não é a sintaxe.

Comment: ainda é possivel ter o resultado que vc quer, e reduzir as classe que fez para criar labels e os elementos, elas mesmo não estão fazendo proveito nenhum das capacidades de uma classe

Comment: Farei oq vc me disse então, se realmente der certo eu voltarei e darei o feedback.

Comment: vai dar certo, eu faço aplicações onde tem uma classe vazia que herda todas as configurações de outras classes, isso inclui funcionabilidade e design

Comment: Oq vc me disse deu mais que certo, talvez seja até mais simples se fizer assim. Vou até disponibilizar o código no github caso outras pessoas tenham esse problema. Mas muito obrigado. Taí o link do git com a solução que vc propôs: https://github.com/bhartolomeu/teste

Comment: a minha solução era mudar a ordem da classes, mudar quem herda de quem, e tambem mudar o super de lugar, fora essa alterações que são quase exclusivas do cabeçalho das classes o resto se mantem inalterado